# Appending multiple rows to csv in python for multiple nested lists

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a function which iterates for loop over some data and output the list of items.

eg: Output of function is :-

```
["A", "B", "C", "D"]
["E", :F", "G", :H"]
["I", "J", "K", "L"]
```

I want to have a single list of this above lists as:-

```
rows = [["A", "B", "C", "D"], ["E", :F", "G", :H"], ["I", "J", "K", "L"]]
```

so that i can use `writer.csv(rows)` to write file to csv with one single header of the csv file.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way, I used it to fetch details from list and append it csv by creating another list of given values`

```
row1 = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
row2 = ["E", :F", "G", :H"]
row3 = ["I", "J", "K", "L"]
rows = row1,row2,row3
print(rows)
```